# livewire alpine flatpickr getting null

Tags: laravel, laravel-livewire, alpine.js

I can't get this to give me the dd() of the date. It keeps coming back as null. i've implemented flatpickr correctly and all works accept when i try to get the actual date. However, when i add an additional button to submit the date with wire directive it works. But i want it to fire when a date is clicked. Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

in my livewire file.

```
public $date;
public function secondStepSubmit()
    { dd('date');
    };
```

in my view

```
 <input x-data x-init="flatpickr($refs.input, null);" wire:change="secondStepSubmit" x-ref="input" type="text" />
   </div>
```

Answer (score 1):

`flatpickr` has its own change event listener.
you can use that to get the value of the date of the input as follows.

```html
<div>
  <input x-data x-init="flatpickr($refs.input, {
    onChange: function(dateObj, dateStr) {
        @this.call('secondStepSubmit', dateStr)
    }
  });" x-ref="input" type="text" />
</div>
```

I have used `@this` blade directive from livewire, we also can use `$wire` from alpine too.

in the Livewire component,

```php
 public function secondStepSubmit($date)
 {
    dd($date);
 }
```